# How to add a button that becomes active after conditions are met js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I continue to make a game on js game "Believe / Don't Believe". Assertion titles appear on the screen one by one. The user responds to each statement in turn. There are 5 statements in total. If the user clicked on the False button then the following statement appears. And if it's true then a description appears. You can go to the next question by clicking on the white circle under the headings, which turns into red if an answer has already been given to it (any), or by clicking on the Next button.

Question:

How do I add a Next button to go to the next question? Until the user has answered the question, it is not active until he gives an answer.
How to add a button that appears after the user answers all the questions (all the balls below are filled)

```js
const data = [
  {stmt: "question 1", desc: "text 1"},
  {stmt: "question 2", desc: "text 2"},
  {stmt: "question 3", desc: "text 3"},
];

let curStmt = 0;

function showStmt(idx) {
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + curStmt).classList.remove('current');
  curStmt = idx;
  document.getElementById('stmt').innerText = data[idx].stmt;
  document.getElementById('desc').innerText = data[idx].desc;
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + idx).classList.add('current');
  applyComplete(data[idx].complete);  
}

function applyComplete(val) {
  val = (val) ? true : false;
  document.getElementById('desc').style.visibility = (val) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('btnTrue').disabled = val;   
  document.getElementById('btnFalse').disabled = val;   
}

function createProgressBar() {
  const parent = document.getElementById('progress');
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.setAttribute('data-idx', i);
    item.id = 'progress-item-' + i;
    item.classList.add('item');
    if (data[i].complete)
      item.classList.add('complete');
    parent.appendChild(item);
  }
}

function btnClick(val) {
  data[curStmt].complete = true;
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + curStmt).classList.add('complete');
  if (val || (curStmt === data.length - 1)) {
    applyComplete(true);
  } else {
    showStmt(curStmt + 1);
  }
}

document.getElementById('progress').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('item')) {
      const newIdx = e.target.getAttribute('data-idx') - 0;
      if (newIdx != curStmt) {
        showStmt(newIdx);
      }
    }
  },
  true
);

createProgressBar();
showStmt(0);
```

```css
.section {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#progress .item {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#progress .item.current {
  border-color: blue;
}

#progress .item.complete {
  background-color: green;
}

#progress .item:not(.complete):hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div id="stmt"></div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
</div>
<div class="section buttons">
  <button id="btnTrue" onclick="btnClick(true)">True</button>
  <button id="btnFalse" onclick="btnClick(false)">False</button>
<div>
<div id="progress" class="section"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {stmt: "question 1", desc: "text 1"},
  {stmt: "question 2", desc: "text 2"},
  {stmt: "question 3", desc: "text 3"},
];

let curStmt = 0;
let answered =[];

function btnNext() {
  console.log('Next button clicked');

  document.getElementById('btnTrue').disabled = false;   
  document.getElementById('btnFalse').disabled = false;  
}
function btnAfterComplete() {
  console.log('Completed button clicked');
}

function showStmt(idx) {
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + curStmt).classList.remove('current');
  curStmt = idx;
  document.getElementById('stmt').innerText = data[idx].stmt;
  document.getElementById('desc').innerText = data[idx].desc;
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + idx).classList.add('current');
  applyComplete(data[idx].complete);  
}

function applyComplete(val) {
  val = (val) ? true : false;
  document.getElementById('desc').style.visibility = (val) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('btnTrue').disabled = val;   
  document.getElementById('btnFalse').disabled = val;   
}

function createProgressBar() {
  const parent = document.getElementById('progress');
  parent.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.setAttribute('data-idx', i);
    item.id = 'progress-item-' + i;
    item.classList.add('item');
    if (data[i].complete)
      item.classList.add('complete');
    parent.appendChild(item);
  }
}

function btnClick(val) {
  data[curStmt].complete = true;
  answered.push(val); 
  document.getElementById('progress-item-' + curStmt).classList.add('complete');
  if (val || (curStmt === data.length - 1)) {
    applyComplete(true);
  } else {
    showStmt(curStmt + 1);

    document.getElementById('btnTrue').disabled = true;   
    document.getElementById('btnFalse').disabled = true;  
  }

  document.getElementById('btnNext').style.visibility = ((curStmt == answered.length) && (answered.length != data.length)) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
  document.getElementById('btnAfterComplete').style.visibility = (answered.length == data.length) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
}

document.getElementById('progress').addEventListener(
  'click',
  function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('item')) {
      const newIdx = e.target.getAttribute('data-idx') - 0;
      if (newIdx != curStmt) {
        showStmt(newIdx);
      }
    }
  },
  true
);

createProgressBar();
showStmt(0);
```

```css
.section {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

#progress .item {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#progress .item.current {
  border-color: blue;
}

#progress .item.complete {
  background-color: green;
}

#progress .item:not(.complete):hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
#btnNext{
  visibility: hidden;
}
#btnAfterComplete{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div id="stmt"></div>
  <div id="desc"></div>
</div>
<div class="section buttons">
  <button id="btnTrue" onclick="btnClick(true)">True</button>
  <button id="btnFalse" onclick="btnClick(false)">False</button>
  <button id="btnNext" onclick="btnNext()">Next</button>
  <button id="btnAfterComplete" onclick="btnAfterComplete()">Complted</button>
<div>
<div id="progress" class="section"></div>
```

Please check the snippet

Comment: Thanks a lot, all is good, but button next dont work

Comment: @AllIn check properly, its working fine, or explain your issue properly

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either by modifying the `disabled` attribute or by adding/removing a class.I recommend using the `disabled` attribute.

### Modifying attribute

You will want to switch between `<button disabled="true">` and `<button disabled="false">`

With javascript, it could look like this:

```
if flag=1: 
    document.getElementById("your-btn").disabled = true;
else: 
    document.getElementById("your-btn").disabled = false;
```

**Example for the same**

```js
const myFunction=()=>{
    document.getElementById("your-btn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<h1>Activate the disabled button conditionally</h1>

<button type="button" id="your-btn" disabled="false">Click Me!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to Activate the previous button</button>
```

**Do tell me wether I was of any help :)**

Comment: Thank you a lot, it was very helpful,  I added a function with disabling the button and everything worked out, but how to make the button appear if all the buttons are pressed, I understand that this is done through document.getElementById('').style = "display:block;" but my second function dont work

Comment: Ok so do you want a ``submit button`` to appear as soon as the person attempts out the last question or you want the button to be there as disabled and become active only when last question is attempted.